# how to check if https sites are supported on windows OS?

Tags: ssl, https, tls1.2, windows-xp-sp3, windows-xp-sp2

Https sites are accessible on windows XP SP3 (after enabling Tls in IE settings/ registry) but not accessible on windows XP SP2(after enabling Tls settings).

How can we programmatically find which OS version and service pack support secured connection (https). So we can use alternative (http) link to connect.

Comment: If you really want to support such insecure systems like XP SP2 you should compile your own SSL library (e.g. OpenSSL or BoringSSL) into your program and use it instead of the insecure junk Microsoft had included in those old Windows versions.

Comment: Thanks for replaying. My requirement is to check if OS supports SSL/TLS secured connection.

Comment: Do you want to establish a secure connection or just find out what the OS supports? For the latter you can only be sure by trying it out because other software like Anti-Virus may intercept SSL connections and establish them on their own using a different version and cipher suite (e.g. Kasperskey does so).